# Ubuntu vm stops responding to host intermittently - but still responding to other network computers?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-server, networking

I'm running an ubuntu server (bitnami lampstack) vm in vmware-server on a windows host machine. The vm every 10-20 seconds stops responding to the host computer for no apparent reason. I can still access the vm and ping it on other network machines and over the remote console on the host, but it will periodically stop talking to the host in every other way -- no ping, no response from the webserver, no dns -- even though all are alive and kicking at the time.

Bridged networking, /etc/network/interfaces is pretty straightforward.

[image: /etc/network/interfaces]

ifconfig:

[image: ifconfig]

*(sorry about the images -- no SSH at the moment)*

When I ping the machine from the windows host, it looks like this:

```
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
[repeat ad infinitum...]
```

Any ideas?

edit - upon further inspection, this is only happening on the host computer. Another network computer doesn't experience the problem -- at least not at the same time, although there is the occasional lone timeout every 30 attempts or so. On the host computer, it normally stops responding like clockwork every 20-second or so. I'm very confused, but I'm starting to think my windows configuration is to blame.

edit2 - tried setting a different ip for the vm, no luck  ... only the host computer is having trouble.

Host computer talking to the router and other computers - *no interruption*

Other computers talking to the vm - *no problem*

Deferred host computer's dns to the router and told the router to connect to the vm's dns - *host is getting uninterrupted dns now*

Host trying to reach the vm 'directly' (ie. by network ip) - *15-seconds on, 15-seconds off. If it's an ip conflict, I have no idea the source.*

Tried assigning the host computer a static network ip address. No difference.

Feels like someone's playing a cruel prank on me or something... anyone have a guess at all as to what I should test at this point?

---

**UPDATE**:

---

I added the host's mac address to the vm's arp cache manually:

```
  arp -s my.host.ip.address my:host:mac:addess
```

This fixed the problem ostensibly -- but when I reboot the vm it starts flaking again.

I don't understand this *at all*. The mac address is still there on reboot if I run `arp -n`, but I have to run that command again to make it respond without interruption. I guess it would help if I knew what the hell I was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar issues:

[here](http://blog.juicylizard.com/?p=194), [here](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/211266)

Cause not determined -- maybe something to do with vmware's bridging or NIC drivers. Plugged host mac into arp cache (`arp -s host.ip host:mac`) in rc.local script. Cheap fix, but I'm done picking at this one.

Comment: Can you clarify _what_ and _how_ you "plugged... ...into" and  _which_ `rc.local` script? I'm not familiar enough to interpolate, but would be happy to +1 if you could spell it out for me

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like a IP address conflict.
Check if no other computer is also using that IP.

Comment: Started doing it again... arghlsd

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems with KVM. The trouble is, I've got two identical host machines and only one is having problems.

Comment: Some blame this on a possible MAC conflict. If you copied/moved a vm from one physical machine to another make sure you tell vmware-server that you `copied`, rather than moved it when prompted. Looking at my router page, I thought my vm was getting assigned the host's mac address; I deleted ( /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules ), removed the vm from vmware-server, added it back and said 'copied' -- got a new mac address. Router still sees the same mac. D'oh. Then, I did the `arp -s` fix I posted. Perhaps someone more familiar with Linux can explain eventually, but I'd try both of those.

Comment: Woops -- sorry, I skimmed over the "KVM" part. The last fix may still apply.

Comment: Yes, manually setting the ARP entries has helped me, but it isn't because of duplicate MAC addresses. For some reason the server doesn't properly respond to ARP requests.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but I was having this same problem.  I think I must've hit "move" instead of "copy" when I setup the VM from a template I had created.  I fixed this problem by editing the VMX file and deleting the lines that start with:

```
ethernet0.addressType
uuid.location =
uuid.bios =
ethernet0.generatedAddress =
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset =
```