# Is there anyone to assign a dynamic IP to a virtual machine?

Tags: ip, virtual-machines, isp, dynamic-ip

My ISP provider can provide aditional *dynamic* IP addresses, Though I'm not sure how will I assign them to my virtual machines. What If I reset my modem ? How will I "get" the extra IP I paid for since it's a dynamic IP address ?
Can someone clarify how my ISP provider can provide aditional dynamic IP addresses ?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but could it be that you're confusing public-facing ip addresses with network ip addresses? If your public-facing ip is 'dynamic', why would you want to assign it to a vm, when it's subject to change? Your ISP can provide you with a 'stitic' public-facing ip for a fee, so that you can always reach your network at the same address. From there you can set up dns, port forwarding and such to reach different servers on the network.

Comment: Is this question more for superuser.com?

Answer (score 1):

Going to take a stab at this, even thought it's hard to tell from your description exactly what you're after. Let's assume you're running a webserver on your virtual machine. To be able to access your virtual machine over the internet you need to:

- configure your vm for *bridged* networking in your hypervisor -- this will allow you to have a local ip address that's accessible through your network
- configure your vm's operating system or your DHCP server to use a static *network* ip address for that machine
- set up your router or access point's port forwarding to point to this network ip on a given port (for example port 80 is typically used for webservers -- it is your browser's default, though it commonly blocked by ISPs, so you may want to use 8080 or something similar)
- very preferably pay your ISP for a static public IP address and define it in your router's settings (you can get away with using a dynamic IP, but it is subject to change who knows how often) *you only need one address*
- If you want to have a domain name, then either get one from a registrar or use something like opendns -- for the former, point the domain to your public ip address. This is where things will get annoying if you're using have a dynamic ip, because it takes a while after you redefine it for the dns to propagate. Hope you like waiting however long that takes.
- point your web browser to your-domain.your-tld:your-port

Networking is [not my expertise](https://serverfault.com/questions/189312/ubuntu-vm-stops-responding-over-the-network-intermittently) (read: I suck at it), so please correct me if I said something wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because my ISP provider does not provide static IP addresses, only dynamics. Yes that's what I'm asking, if it is possible to assign the dynamic ip to my virtual machine. If will only change If I reset my router right ? Then I could simply reassign them again ?

Comment: You should post this a comment instead of an answer to avoid confusion. And to answer your last two questions, 'not necessarily' and 'what do you mean by reassign?'. I think you are misunderstanding concepts here. What is it you exactly that you are trying to achieve?